# Not able to link partner portal account and AppExchange provider profile

Tags: appexchange, isv, licenses, partner-portal

I have developed application which I want to publish on AppExchange. Now, I registered on appExchange with developer account, and created partner portal account and Change Partnership on Publisher Profile. It shows "No partnership selected" only.

As per following link

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008unmIAA

It says I need to be partner of Partner Portal. but, I have already sign up on partner profile. and can not link up with AppExchange provider profile.